# Copy or show the primary key value into another table as foreign key APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have two tables A and B .i want to copy or show the primary key column value from table A in the foreign key column in table B respectively .is there any method kindly help me.

Regards,

Comment: So you want to use primary key of table A as foreign key in table B?

Comment: No i want to call or show the primary key value of table A as a foreign key value in Table B

Comment: Could you be more specific as what you are looking for or provide what is your expected output with some sample data?

Comment: i have two Tables A and B. The Primary key column is related to as a foreign key in table B. when i inset the data in the primary key column of table A,the same data of Primary key in Table A is not shown in Table B column which is foreign key. Plz Check the image http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/5498/36379097.png .Here the Vendor_InvoiceDetSerNo is Foreign Key Column.

Comment: If primary key of table A is referred as foreign key in table B, without inserting into table B, it would not be available. You need to insert that. So you could use some trigger or from application you should be able to do that.

Comment: Can u send me the syntax code for the trigger ?

Comment: I have question though, how do you populate or insert data into table B?

Comment: I simply Insert the data in the tables but i dont insert the data in Foreign key column because i want to take value from Primary key column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate your primary key value while populating table B or by using a trigger when  you are populating table A.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id1 NUMBER, dt DATE);

 ALTER TABLE t1 ADD (
  CONSTRAINT t1_pk
 PRIMARY KEY
 (id1));


CREATE TABLE t2 (id2 NUMBER, id1 NUMBER, dt2 DATE);

 ALTER TABLE t2 ADD (
  CONSTRAINT t2_pk
 PRIMARY KEY
 (id2));
ALTER TABLE t2
 ADD CONSTRAINT t2_r01
 FOREIGN KEY (id2)
 REFERENCES t1 (id1);
```

First Approach, by this way you could populate second table when you are inserting values.

```
INSERT INTO t1
  VALUES   (1, SYSDATE
              );

INSERT INTO t2
  VALUES   (1, 1, SYSDATE
              );
```

With trigger, so when values are inserted into first table second tables values are populated using a trigger. So primary key value of first table is being inserted into foreign key of table 2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
    AFTER INSERT
    ON t1
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t2
      VALUES   (1, :new.id1, SYSDATE
                  );
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (TO_CHAR (SQLERRM (-20299)));
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (TO_CHAR (SQLERRM (-20298)));
END;
```

Comment: Let me chek this trigger Code  ...Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Then it is more simple, either in item level or page level when you insert in table 1, insert into table 2 at the same time. There are a couple of options to do that in APEX.